# Wordpress page template dont appear inside Template Dropdown List

Tags: wordpress, templates, caching, themes, admin

I've just add a new custom template file on my WP theme folder.
This new template begin like my others template files :

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: My Template Name
*/
```

Strangly, this new template do not appear inside Template Dropdown List inside admin page editing.

It seem to have a WP caching issue or something like this... I've tried to clear the cookies and cache of my browser, clear my server cache, and more... but it do not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more than an hour searching the Web and testing many things, I've found that I need to change my theme version to let WP know the new files structure (*inside style.css*) :

```
/*
Theme Name: My Theme Name
Version: 1.0.0
*/
```

TO

```
/*
Theme Name: My Theme Name
Version: 1.0.1
*/
```

And it finally work!
Hope it will help someone else ;)

Comment: I seem to be able to create a Template and successfully make it appear in the relevant drop down menu, without the need to reference any file version. Would be interested to know whether anybody else has come across this.

Comment: I've never heard of this happening, the official WordPress site even shows how to create a global template like this <?php /* Template Name: Example Template */ ?>  No mention of theme versions anywhere...

Comment: Sorry, some informations missing... It happened on last WP update to 4.9 version. Before this version, I never had this problem. Also, the theme version is inside style.css, not declared inside each template files. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you have WP-CLI installed, try to run `wp cache flush` or

you can put this code into your functions.php

```
function fix_template_caching( WP_Screen $current_screen ) {
    if ( ! in_array( $current_screen->base, array( 'post', 'edit', 'theme-editor' ), true ) ) {
        return;
    }
    $theme = wp_get_theme();
    if ( ! $theme ) {
        return;
    }
    $cache_hash    = md5( $theme->get_theme_root() . '/' . $theme->get_stylesheet() );
    $label         = sanitize_key( 'files_' . $cache_hash . '-' . $theme->get( 'Version' ) );
    $transient_key = substr( $label, 0, 29 ) . md5( $label );
    delete_transient( $transient_key );
}

add_action( 'current_screen', 'fix_template_caching' );
```

Reference: [Fix for theme template file caching https://gist.github.com/westonruter/6c2ca0e5a4da233bf4bd88a1871dd950](https://gist.github.com/westonruter/6c2ca0e5a4da233bf4bd88a1871dd950)

:)

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was to change the file permissions for the missing template. For some reason, the permissions were incorrect when I uploaded the file, but after changing its chmod permissions to 755, then template appeared in the dropdown as expected.

Reference: https://vanseodesign.com/wordpress/wp-page-templates-dropdown/